# Number of permutations given a sequence of $5$ letters that are offset from $1-9$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

If I have a random sequence of letters "AOKNG", and I'd like to find how many permutations of this can be formed given a character offset from $1-9$.

So, offset the first character "A" $9$ times would give:

- BOKNG
- COKNG
- DOKNG
- EOKNG
- FOKNG
- GOKNG
- HOKNG
- IOKNG
- JOKNG

= 9 permutations.

Then, offset the second for each of the first $9$ permutations, and so on.

I have done this programmatically, and I have a total of $32768$ permutations. I'd like to understand how I would go about getting to this number mathematically given the above scenario.

"AOKNG" itself is not a permutation, it is the starting sequence. Take each letter of "AOKNG" and advance it x number of times up until $9$. So "A" would become "B", would become "C".

Advance the first letter to "B", would become "BOKNG" ($1$ permutation), then repeat this nine times, replacing the first letter with C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J.

This gives us $9$ permutations.

Now do the same for every letter in the starting sequence to find every possible  combination of letters.

**There are $9$ possible values in total for each of the $5$ letters in the starting sequence.**

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Is AOKNG one of the allowed words? In that case you have 10 permutations, counting the original . Is APKNG an allowed permutation?

Comment: "AOKNG" is the starting sequence. So there are 9 possible values in total for each of the 5 letters in the starting sequence.

Comment: But in your question you include up to JOKNG, which makes for ten permutations for the first letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a basic interpretation of your question, you have 10 possible characters for each position in the 5-letter word. So the total number of possible words is $10^5=100,000$.

Comment: So the answer to my questions was as simple as 9^5. My calculation in my code was correct, I just missed 1 digit off so was doing 8^5 which is why I was getting 32,768 results. Anyway, thanks.